# excel-read-file version 5.7.1 fails with strange error in node version 20 and 21

Tags: node.js, excel

I am using the excel module excel-read-file to read excel files. However, when I import the readXslFile, an error is thrown with the following code. It is really a simple class

```
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file'

     class XlsReader {
         bufferReader  = async(buffer:Uint8Array): Promise<any[]> => {
         return readXlsxFile(Buffer.from(buffer))      
     }
     
   }

   export default XlsReader
```

I get the following error when I build the project. I am just using a simple command in scripts in my package.json

"build": tsc - p tsconfig.json

```
node_modules/read-excel-file/index.d.ts:7:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './types.d' or its corresponding type declarations.
```